# Possible different definitions of determinant of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I was thinking of an interesting question. What's the relation between $\text{det}(A)$ and $\sum_{\sigma,\eta}\text{sgn}(\sigma\eta)a_{\eta(1),\sigma(1)}a_{\eta(2),\sigma(2)}...a_{\eta(n),\sigma(n)}$?

I feel like they are multiple of each other by some constants depending on $n$.

Thank you in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each fixed $\sigma$, reindex the sum over $\eta$ by replacing $\eta$ with $\eta \circ \sigma$. Now reorder the $n$ factors to get rid of the $\sigma$'s . Using the multiplicativity of the sign character you'll just get the usual Laplace expansion formula for each $\sigma$, so it's $n! \det(A)$.